# Where do I place the return?

Tags: c, arduino

I am writing a function to check the input by a float sensor. The sensor gives a digital ON/OFF signal. This is what I wrote,

```
int level_check(int sensorType, int FloatSensor)
{
  int level = 0;
  int buttonState = digitalRead(FloatSensor);
  if (sensorType == 1)
  {
    if (buttonState == LOW) 
      { 
          int level = 0;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - LOW"); 
    } 
      else 
      { 
          int level = 1;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - HIGH" ); 
      }
  }
  else
  {
    if (buttonState == LOW) 
      { 
          int level = 1;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - LOW"); 
    } 
      else 
      { 
          int level = 0;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - HIGH" ); 
      }
  }
  return level;
}
```

However, the level is always returned as 0 wherever I call it irrespective of the sensor output.
If I make this change, the code works as expected.

```
if (buttonState == LOW) 
      { 
          int level = 0;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - LOW"); 
          return level;
    } 
      else 
      { 
          int level = 1;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - HIGH" ); 
          return level;
      }
```

What is wrong with the code above? Why can't I use *return* at the end?

Comment: `int level = 0;` inside the sub-blocks declare *new* variables of the same name. Which is different to the one being returned. Remove the `int` from all those lines so that there is only one `int level` at the top of the function and thus only one variable of that name.

Comment: In your function, you are declaring `level` at the top level, and returning it it at the end.  Within each `if`/`else` clause, you are declaring additional variables with the same name.  Those declarations mask the top-level declaration. Within those blocks, all references to `level` refer to those nested declarations, which go out of scope when you exit the block.  The top-level instance of `level` is therefore a constant zero.  To fix it, just change the inner declarations to assignments, e.g. change `int level = 1;` to `level = 1;`  That way they will refer to the top-level `level`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the correct code. The `int level = //something;` that you create inside the if lies in the scope of the if block only and the `int level = //something;` that you create inside the else lies in the scope of the else block only. `int level = 0;` in line 2 of your code lies in the scope of the function `level_check`.

```
int level_check(int sensorType, int FloatSensor)
{
  int level = 0;
  int buttonState = digitalRead(FloatSensor);
  if (sensorType == 1)
  {
    if (buttonState == LOW) 
      { 
          level = 0;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - LOW"); 
    } 
      else 
      { 
          level = 1;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - HIGH" ); 
      }
  }
  else
  {
    if (buttonState == LOW) 
      { 
          level = 1;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - LOW"); 
    } 
      else 
      { 
          level = 0;
          Serial.println( "WATER LEVEL - HIGH" ); 
      }
  }
  return level;
}
```